# Can you tell me why this isn't working?

Tags: javascript, css, youtube, youtube-api

Everything was working fine yesterday. I have not touched the code nor made any changes. To clarify what isn't working, when I type my term to search and hit "find" or "enter" nothing happens. The bulk of the code that makes that work is the JavaScript with the exception of the call to the input on the HTML.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/weqome/edit?output) is the jsbin. Any ideas would be appreciated. I also tried a new API key and that doesn't work either.

Comment: What doesn't work?  Please be specific in your question.

Comment: It works fine for me... What's your term exactly that you're putting in to the search box.  And what browser are you using?

Comment: You should also paste your code into the question.

Comment: I tried cats, waves basically any word it doesn't work. I have tried in Firefox, Firefox developer edition, chrome and chrome canary to no avail.

Comment: @Will I keep getting mixed reviews on that. I have been down voted for pasting code when I have the jsbin link.

Comment: One reason why people recommend that you have the code pasted on Stack Overflow in the body of the question is to make sure that whoever comes searching for a problem like yours would be able to see the code that the question was about in case the link you gave goes down, or the contents of the page you're linking to get changed where it wouldn't be relevant anymore to the question you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined the issue. Googles AJAX API was down. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your line:

`video.src = video_url;`

you need the following line:

`$('#video').attr('src', video_url);`

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work for me. I placed it in that function and outside to see if it was a hoisting issue, but still to no avail.

Comment: It might be something else that's not working, this fix makes it work in IE, Chrome, and Firefox for me.  What do you get in the jsbin console tab?  Also, can you please try to access (in a new tab) the youtube url that you're trying to put together in the javascript (in other words, try hardcoding the URL and see if it works)?  Are you getting any errors when you access that URL?

Comment: Sure. I don't have anything in the console. Which is strange. And when I try to call a function, everything is undefined.

Comment: As for when pasting the youtube_url in a new tab, it just loads forever. When I try to access the video_url, I get no issues.

Comment: So, paste in here (show me) what you get when you call this URL in Chrome: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&q=cats&maxResults=1&key=AIzaSyDiUEkwoldcB9qgRreOsaiyu2Nlj8U-03c

Comment: When I paste that URL in chrome, the page is just blank. It takes forever to load and then it just times out.

Comment: This is probably the problem.  The ajax call never comes back for you apparently.  I get the following:{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/r2frS0wVoPq4V5tbLBG_Xgs9kTc\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/fajvWkcINbkGu63Hk0ZaQOmM0Bs\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "O1KW3ZkLtuo"
   }
  }
 ]
}

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what happens when I try to access that link : [screenshot] (http://i.imgur.com/Atw1vQE.png)

Comment: The thing is everything worked fine until this morning. I haven't changed anything. I went to a proxy and I saw what you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81581/discussion-between-3abqari-and-jshuadvd).